# After installing compizconfig-settings manager settings no longer work

Tags: unity, compiz, settings

Heres my issue, i work with ubuntu and set up a very effective keyboard shortcut system that, after i had to install compizconfig-settings manager stopped working. In dconf the keybinds are still correctly set, however they don't seem to work.

The specific settings i use extensively (and would like to keep on using) is around the super key with the numbers and arrows to achieve different functions.

Now, however it seems that the only use the super key has is for window interaction which is of no use to me (super - 1 opens the first in the launcher etc).

In addition to this if i change some configuration in the system settings, like the icon size or the auto-hide feature of the unity launcher, it will no longer work.

Can someone shed some light on what may be happening?

Thanks in advance.